# Is it able to return data portion by portion

Tags: jersey, apache-poi, apache-tomee

I have some client, REST web servise and database. Database has big tables (10 million rows). 
I need search some data in db (1 million results), put it in excel file with apache poi and return to the client. The problem is retrieving data from database and forming file can be longer than 1h. Is it exists a way to return data portionally (retrieve 1000 rows, return, retrieve next 1000, return and so on)?

Comment: I think is not possible because for each request you can return only one response. but 1h seems to much. are you using some ORM?

Comment: however you could try using MemPOI that should ensure stable performance. take a look at the Performance paragraph https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI

Comment: if you tried mempoi please let me know if it  endured the workload or not

Comment: @firegloves im sorry, but yes, i use orm, so i think that option won't fit to my application

Comment: Your problem is the ORM. ORM needs a lot of execution time, you could try a mixed approach not using ORM only for excel exports